# Combining scroll with many if statements that change the same div

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to understand JavaScript and it seems that I can't properly write a function with `if` and `else if` statements.
I want to have a function where I scroll down the page and the background color of a `div` element changes multiple times. So, if I scroll 50px the background is in one color, then I keep scrolling until 300px and it turns into blue, then I keep scrolling until 600px and it gets red, and so on.
This is the code I tried to write, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it because of the final `else`? Or because there is a contradiction between the `if`s?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 60) {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "test";
    }
    else if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "test2";
    } 
    else if (document.body.scrollTop > 600 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600) {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "test3";
    }
     else {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "";
    }
}
```

```css
.test {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.test2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.test3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:1500px">

<p>Scroll down this page</p>

<p id="myP" style="position:fixed">hello!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is because your first if is always true. Because once you are over 60px you class test is added. You should limit it like this:

```
if ((document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 60)
     && (document.body.scrollTop < 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 300)) {
        document.getElementById("myP").className = "test";
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was what i was thinking too, but i didn't know how to solve it. does this work also if i keep going? with other && and then the code for 600px?

Comment: You just limit every if statement to the number from the next. Like `> 60 && < 300`, next is `> 300 && < 600`